# groovy multiple file rename: not working

Tags: groovy

I am trying to achieve a small task of renaming multiple CSV files present in a directory in a specific fashion. The code is pretty simple but not sure for what reason it doesn't show any output at all, neither the job gets done. Can someone please take a look into my code and let me know where I went wrong?

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*
import static groovy.io.FileVisitResult.*

try{
def workDir = 'C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\testFiles'
def userInputFileName = "ppi"
def meds = "11223344"
new File("${workDir}").eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    if(it.name.endsWith('.csv')) {
        println(it)
        it.renameTo(new File(${userInputFileName} + "_" + ${meds} + "_" + file.getName(), file.getName()))
    }
}
}
catch(Exception e){
println(e)
}

Existing File Name: file-234-ggfd-43445fh.csv
To be converted file name: ${userInputFileName}_${meds}_file-234-ggfd-43445fh.csv
```

Comments?
Groovy version: `2.4.15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing $variableName and variableName.

```
  it.renameTo(new File(${userInputFileName} + "_" + ${meds} + "_" + file.getName(), file.getName()))
```

The $variableName is meant for using in String ( GString) type situation. Following should  work.

```
 it.renameTo(new File(userInputFileName + "_${meds}_" + file.getName(), file.getName()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using `data` as a directory. Note that it breaks some lines apart for clarity:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*
import static groovy.io.FileVisitResult.*

def workDir = 'data'
def userInputFileName = "ppi"
def meds = "11223344"

new File("${workDir}").eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    if (it.name.endsWith('.csv')) {
        println(it)
        def destPath = "${it.parent}${File.separator}${userInputFileName}_${meds}_${it.name}" 
        def dest = new File(destPath)
        it.renameTo(dest)
        assert dest.exists()
        assert ! it.exists()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for comments:

There were many mistakes in your code. Not groovy mistakes. Programming mistakes.

Here's the working code:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*
import static groovy.io.FileVisitResult.*

try {
    def workDir = 'C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/testFiles' as File
    def userInputFileName = "ppi"
    def meds = "11223344"
    workDir.eachFileRecurse(FILES) { file ->
        if (file.name.endsWith('.csv')) {
            println(file)
            def target = new File(workDir, "${userInputFileName}_${meds}_${file.name}")
            file.renameTo(target)
            assert target.exists()
            assert !file.exists()
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    println(e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ioteq. Appreciate the critics; will try to improve on your suggestion.